# Socket.emit() not sending data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am making a game, and I want to send data between the client and the server. I started with a tutorial to figure out how to do this, however, even when I copy the socket.emit code to emit my variable op1 exactly as before, I get no response.

```js
//server

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log('Server started.');

var optypes = [Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]

var op1 = [450, 600, optypes[0]];

function OpSend () {
 io.sockets.emit('operations', op1);
}
 
var io = require ('socket.io')(serv,{});

setInterval(function() {
  
  OpSend();
 
  var pack = [];
    
  for(var i in PLAYER_LIST) {
   var player = PLAYER_LIST[i];
   player.updatePosition();
   pack.clear();
   pack.push({
    x:player.x,
    y:player.y,
    number:player.number
   });
   
  }
  
  for(var i in SOCKET_LIST) {
  var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
  socket.emit('newPositions', pack);
  
  
  }
   },1000/500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
//client

 var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
 ctx.font = '30px Arial';
 
 var socket = io();

 var fakeX;

 var op1 = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  type: 0
 };
 
 
 function drawCanvas() {
  drawBoard();
  drawColors();
  drawOperations();
  drawRestrictions();
 }
 


 function drawOperations() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red"
  ctx.beginPath();
  //ctx.rotate(180*Math.PI/180);
  ctx.fillText("U", op1.x-20, op1.y);
 }

 

 socket.on('newPositions',function(data) {
  drawCanvas();
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   ctx.fillStyle = "black";
   ctx.fillText(data[i].number, data[i].x, data[i].y);
  }
 });
  
function checkOP() {
 console.log("checked")
 socket.on('operations', function(data) {
  //fakeX = data;
  console.log("got it");
 });
}

 setInterval(function(){
  checkOP();
 }, 1000/500)

 
</script>
```

How come when I emit "newPositions," everything goes to plan, but with "operations," it doesn't seem to go through? Is it not being sent? Is it not being received? I am pretty new at this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function that defined socket over and over again in setInterval which isn't needed. What you need to configure the `socket.on` statically like you did for `newPositions`

```js
//server

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log('Server started.');

var optypes = [Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6), Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]

var op1 = [450, 600, optypes[0]];

function OpSend () {
 io.sockets.emit('operations', op1);
}
 
var io = require ('socket.io')(serv,{});

setInterval(function() {
  
  OpSend();
 
  var pack = [];
    
  for(var i in PLAYER_LIST) {
   var player = PLAYER_LIST[i];
   player.updatePosition();
   pack.clear();
   pack.push({
    x:player.x,
    y:player.y,
    number:player.number
   });
   
  }
  
  for(var i in SOCKET_LIST) {
  var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
  socket.emit('newPositions', pack);
  
  
  }
   },1000/500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
//client

 var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
 ctx.font = '30px Arial';
 
 var socket = io();

 var fakeX;

 var op1 = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  type: 0
 };
 
 
 function drawCanvas() {
  drawBoard();
  drawColors();
  drawOperations();
  drawRestrictions();
 }
 


 function drawOperations() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red"
  ctx.beginPath();
  //ctx.rotate(180*Math.PI/180);
  ctx.fillText("U", op1.x-20, op1.y);
 }

 

 socket.on('newPositions',function(data) {
  drawCanvas();
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   ctx.fillStyle = "black";
   ctx.fillText(data[i].number, data[i].x, data[i].y);
  }
 });
  
 socket.on('operations', function(data) {
  //fakeX = data;
  console.log("got it");
 });


 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still does not work. I'm not getting "got it" in the console.